# intent.getBooleanExtra causing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, android-intent, crash, out-of-memory

I am experiencing an issue with `intent.getBooleanExtra` that is triggering an `OutOfMemoryError` exception.

The crash occurred on an Android 5.0 phone (Asus ZenFone 2 ZE551ML), with more than 1GB of free RAM and more than 6GB of free disk space.

Crash stack:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: int[] of length 2015679692 would overflow
       at android.util.ArrayMap.allocArrays(ArrayMap.java:198)
       at android.util.ArrayMap.ensureCapacity(ArrayMap.java:309)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:219)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.getBoolean(BaseBundle.java:658)
       at android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(Bundle.java:603)
       at android.content.Intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.java:4781)
       at MyClass.onActivityCreated(MyClass.java:33)
```

And my code looks like:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = activity.getIntent();
        if (intent != null && !intent.getBooleanExtra(ActionIntent.MYCONSTANT, false)) {
        ....
        }
    }
```

Any Idea why I got that crash, with just the `getBooleanExtra` call and with more than 1GB of free RAM?

Comment: Well, `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: int[] of length 2_015_679_692 ` ... sounds like you try to create some really huge array. Less than the theoretical max of 2,147,483,647 ... for array sizes, but well, do you really think 2 billion ints fit into 1 GB?

Comment: I am just calling `getBooleanExtra()` so the Array creation seems to be made by the system.

Comment: Please show the intent that starts all this. Start your post with it. It seems you are putting more in it than only a boolean.

Comment: Exactly. Probably you have something *else* in your intent, and that first getXXX() call tries to "build" all the other elements in your intent.

Comment: The crash occurs when attempting to unparcel the "extras" `Bundle` in the `Intent`. Either you've put something really large in there or you've somehow corrupted the `Bundle`.